# How to avoid the checkbox 'Stop execute scripts on this page' in the Javascript message box?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I avoid the checkbox 'Stop execute scripts on this page' in the Javasript message box?
[image]

Regards,
David

Comment: I have never seen this before. Where is this from?

Comment: by sending less `alert`s. In most browsers the first and perhaps the second alert don't have the checkbox and then it starts appearing.

Comment: Is this from Alerts or from a script gone cpu crazy? I know in Chrome that an out of control script that ties up the browser will eventually cause a halt scripts message box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, you can't.  It's placed there for a reason - to stop sites that try to prevent you from leaving by popping up a new dialog box everytime you try to exit.  In most browsers, like @Bazzz said, they don't show this until the second or third alert in a row.

Comment: Key example of this: Rick Roll sites that spam the lyrics

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. It's a built-in feature in some browsers to prevent alert/confirm dialogs loop which can block whole browser. I can't image situation when many dialog downloads can be a good user experience.

Anyway, you don't have to rely on browser - just use custom dialogs in HTML/CSS which you can control as you wish.

Comment: Kiseļovs...ok There are two textboxes. Both are mandatory.If somebody clicks the save button without mandatory fields. Then this Javascript fires. If he checks the 'Stop executing sripts in the webpage' checkbox and clicks the save button again What will happen?

Comment: @David John Form still should not get submitted if it's not valid. Also you need server-side validation because you can't rely on Javascript.